# How to have the same CSS variable names in children components

Tags: css, angular

Hey there I have multiple components within each-other.

I want them all to have the CSS variable --border-radius and pass the value down to the children component's variable.

I have 4 components deep but for this example I'll simplify it to 2 components to illustrate my problem.

**Component A**

```
:host{
    --border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);

    component-b {
       --border-radius: var(--border-radius);    
    }
}
```

**Component B**

```
:host{
    --border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
```

When I inspect component B in the browser, I see it's border-radius is set to "var(--border-radius)" instead of the expected "50%".

Is there a way to accomplish this?

EDIT:
Note Component A & Component B are both stand-alone components that should be able to take the CSS property --border-radius in. The issue is with passing the variable property down to the next component that has the same variable name.

Comment: the browser will alwyas show you *var(--border-radius)*, you need to check the computed tab to see the value

Comment: Thanks, however that's not the problem. It's not computing the border-radius at all.

Comment: Not sure I understand since in component B in your example you're explicitly overriding that referenced var with `--border-radius: 0;` so one would expect it to be `0` not `50%` as it sits currently and to @TemaniAfif's point if you're just inspecting the element then it will read as `var(--border-radius)` in the inspection but will show the **actual value** in the computed styles... It would be tough to "not compute" at all since the user agent will always supply a fallback.

Comment: @ChrisW. let's say i have 4 components that are all standalone and take in the property --border-radius.
I have one big component that is made up of those components within each-other. Ex: D is inside C which is inside B which is inside the big component A. 
I want to set --border-radius on A and have it reflected on B,C & D

Comment: Unless maybe what you're actually looking for is A: `:host {--border-radius: 50%;}` B:`host-context(--border-radius) { border-radius: var(--border-radius); }`

Comment: @ChrisW. host-context is for defining properties based on the parent element. That would have to get pretty specific for each use case. I was more looking for a solution to set a variable once and have it trickle that variable down to the internal components. I could just give all of them a different variable name --border-radius-component-a , --border-radius-component-b .... which would work but that'd be pretty ugly

Comment: Personally I just use Sass vars for these scenarios and let the precompile handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to create a CSS variable that stored the border radius of your elements, you can use the :root selector to create a global variable, example :

```
:root { --border-radius: 50%; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to pass it down between these components, not the entire program.

Comment: The ng-deep selector would still have the same problem I'm having..

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after thinking about how CSS works for awhile with the fact that it cascades the styles down... I came to the conclusion that I was thinking about the variables incorrectly.

The way it works is:

Component A defines --border-radius as 10px;

Component B does not define it, but instead uses it if it exists, otherwise uses a default value. By not defining it at the beginning of B, it will automatically cascade down from A.

**Component A**

```
:host {
    --border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
}
```

**Component B**

```
:host{
    border-radius: var(--border-radius, 0);
}
```

In that example, B will default to 0, but accept A's 10px or any other value you pass directly into B.